# a general solution of an ODE system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the general solution of the following ODE system of equations?
$$
\vec{x}'(t)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)\vec{x}(t)
$$
Note that this matrix has complex eigenvalues and i'm interested in the real solution

Answer (score 4):

Solve for eigenvalues first and you get $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=\pm\sqrt i$
The next step is to find the corresponding eigenvectors.

From the real eigenvalue/eigenvector pair, we get one solution: $e^{\lambda_1t}\vec{v}_1$;
If the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{2,3}=\alpha\pm\beta i$ with eigenvectors $\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3$, we have $e^{\alpha t}(\cos(\beta t)+i\sin(\beta t))\vec{v}_2$

Answer (score 1):

You are solving something like $x'(t) = Ax(t)$, so if you diagonalize, i.e. compute $A=SDS^{-1}$, then you can do a coordinate transform $y(t)=S^{-1}x$. Then multiply with $S^{-1}$ on both side to get a equivalent ODE given by:$$y'(t)=Dy(t).$$
This should be easy to solve for you. Once you have the general solution for $y$, you construct $x(t) = Sy(t)$.

Comment: but this matrix has complex eigenvalues and i'm interested in the real solutions

Comment: That's not a problem, your solution for $y(t)$ may be complex, but you need to finish the computations. For example, the eigenvalues are $\pm i$ and $1$ right? So you will have three solutions for each entry of $y$, namely $e^{it}$, $e^{-it}$ and $e^{t}$. If you compute $x(t) = Sy(t)$ you will find yourself adding, for example, $e^{it} + e^{-it}$. With Euler's formula and some other stuff, you should see that this is equal to a real cosine.